# Is a virtual machine with ros-kinetic available anywhere?

Tags: ros

I want to learn `ros-kinetic` from a virtual machine. I found that `ros-indigo`  is available from [nootrix](https://nootrix.com/diy-tutos/ros-indigo-virtual-machine/); similarly, is there a virtual machine with ros-kinetic version available anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

Hey I was wondering this same thing.. After some research there are some docker containers that you can look at https://hub.docker.com/_/ros/ . If you want a virtual machine im actually working on a vagrant file that does exactly this as we speak. https://github.com/joepuzzo/vagrant-turtlebot 
You could fork that and tweak it to your needs.

---

Comment: glad to see a reply, i have no knowledge of using docker or vagrant. is it some sort of running scripts to automate the process? but then it will download package from internet and install right? i am looking for a prebuild  machine so that i can download and use it . ubuntu is not my cup of tea, every now and then some problem happens making it unusable, so instead of reinstalling one by one  from scratch i want a prebuild machine so i can just use it by opening through virtual box

Comment: Totally get that! Yeah so if you want to go down the virtualbox route I would highly recommend you learn a little about vagrant for the exact reasons you described. So What is vagrant? Vagrant is an awesome tool that allows you to build virtual machines from a text file. Why is it so awesome? Because all you need is virtual box and vagrant, and you now have access to thousands of virtual machine definitions ( known as boxes ). The cool part is if you run into issues you can just set up your own box definition by tweaking the `Vagrant` file.

Comment: At its core its really simple. Instead of installing ubuntu and following the step by step guide on ROS's website to install every dependency and stuff to get your machine up and running, you write all the steps in the `Vagrant` file, run `vagrant up` from your terminal ( might differ for windows ) and your new virtual machine will show up in virtual-box.

Comment: just installed vagrant after ur post i have to see how to use it.. btw can u tell whats in this https://app.vagrantup.com/bkinman/boxes/ubuntu1604_kinetic

Comment: So its published on vagrants hub but i cant seem to find his vagrantfile. In vagrant you can create and publish a "box" from a vagrantfile. This is what this guy "bkinman" did here.. it looks like he did not include description unfortunately. Typically you pull from well known boxes such as https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64 . And build your own.. i would recommend you build your own from scratch because you have more control. That being said i totally get the frustration of this.. it should be more simple than this to get ROS up and running.

Comment: and is there anyway to somehow use the existing ubuntu.iso file to be useful to vagrant than downloading everything

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/XSmuXe4.png i used your vagrant but why is there many missing apps, and there is no shutdown option?

Comment: @SubhasshMahenthren sorry forgot to mention. There is a line in the vagrantfile   `config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop"` .... The `--no-install-recommends` will only install basic stuff. You can open terminal with ctr alt t or somthing like that

Comment: vagrant halt from directory with vagrantfile will shut down vm

Comment: ok thank you, i am managing to use it for ros purposes

Answer (score 0):

This is the only Vagrant box I've found for `kinetic`:

https://app.vagrantup.com/pstizzy/boxes/ubuntu-xenial64-ros-kinetic-desktop-full

Answer (score -1):

There is an [online resource](http://www.theconstructsim.com/) I have come across that is geared towards learning. It is a paid subscription and I have not personally used the online environment. I have used some of their tutorials and it seems helpful.